# Is this relation, $xRy=\{(1,2),(2,3)\}$, transitive?

Tags: relations

$xRy=\{(1,2),(2,3)\}$

I'm asking because I was reading on antisymmetry from this question

[Antisymmetric Relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255683/antisymmetric-relations)

I may very well just be confused, but the relation doesn't state that 1 does not correspond to 3 as well. At the same time though, I would assume that it would only be transitive if the relation were

$xRy=\{(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)\}$

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are correct that $(1,3)$ is missing for this relation to be transitive.

Comment: As an aside, since you were reading on antisymmetry, I suggest taking a look at [this post of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475354/can-a-relation-be-both-symmetric-and-antisymmetric-or-neither/1475381#1475381) which may help clarify things further.

Answer (score 2):

The relation $\mathcal{R}=\{(1,2),(2,3)\}$ (*note, this is the relation $\mathcal{R}$, not "$x\mathcal{R}y$" which is a statement not the relation as a whole*) is not transitive because for it to have been transitive we would have required that for every possible choice of $x,y,z$ (*possibly repeating*), if we had $x\mathcal{R}y$ and $y\mathcal{R}z$ that we would also have needed $x\mathcal{R}z$.

Since $(1,2)\in\mathcal{R}$ and $(2,3)\in\mathcal{R}$ but $(1,3)\not\in\mathcal{R}$ the relation is not transitive.

"*The relation doesn't state that 1 does not correspond to 3 as well.*"  On the contrary, the relation is very specifically defined to include those things listed in it and *only* those things listed in it.  Since $(1,3)$ is not listed in the definition of $\mathcal{R}$, that directly confirms that $1$ is not related to $3$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  Since $1R2$ and $2R3$ are true but $1R3$ is not true, the relation is not transitive.